# error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct ...'

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have following code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct StackEntry StackEntry;
typedef struct StackEntry
{
    int data;
    StackEntry *next;
};

StackEntry* createStack()
{
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    StackEntry *stack = createStack(); //Error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct StackEntry *' using type 'StackEntry'
}
```

I am getting error `incompatible types when initializing type 'struct StackEntry *' using type 'StackEntry'` as shown above. I am revisiting C after a long time. What I am doing wrong here?

**Edit (Super apologies)**

I unnecessarily simplified stuff. I felt that will help highlight the error code. My original setup had a lot of code. It was working too. But now it broke. So I gathered all the related code and put it here. I should have first tried putting it all in one file and run. I am very sorry for not doing that. But now I have stripped down all possible code and able to reproduce the error. Here it is:

**algorithms.h**

```
#ifndef ALGORITHMS_H_
#define ALGORITHMS_H_

StackEntry createStack();

#endif /* ALGORITHMS_H_ */
```

**datastructures.h**

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURES_H_
#define DATASTRUCTURES_H_

typedef struct StackEntry StackEntry;

struct StackEntry
{
    int data;
    StackEntry *next;
};
#endif /* DATASTRUCTURES_H_ */
```

**stack.c**

```
#include "datastructures.h"
#include "stdio.h"

StackEntry* createStack()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

**Main.c**

```
#include "datastructures.h"
#include "algorithms.h"

int main()
{
    StackEntry *stack = createStack(); //Error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct StackEntry *' using type 'StackEntry'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why  the second typedef is there,as it will be ignored?

Comment: Do you still have the error after removing the useless second `typedef`?

Comment: Ahh I missed it...it should not be there...btw why compiler did not considered it as error...?

Comment: Is this C or C++?  They are two separate languages and handle class names differently

Comment: ohh this is in `.c` file

Comment: @Mahesha999 You should compile with `-Wall` option **at least**. And `-Wextra` `-Werror` are recommended.

Comment: the question remains what that useless `typedef` mean? it should mean something right? since compiler did not gave me any error on that.

Comment: gcc 4.9.3 MinGW on Window 10, using it in Eclipse

Comment: surprisingly ideone does not give me any error http://ideone.com/ehrDKV

Comment: @Mahesha999 This is strange, I use MinGW gcc 4.5.4 (three years old) and I get a warning but no error.

Comment: Your struct usage is correct in C. Your code would not produce the error you claim. However, there is another error: `NULL` is an undeclared identifier. This proves that the real code is different to what you actually compiled otherwise you would have gotten the same error.   Please make sure that you have posted **exactly** the code you compiled to get the error.

Comment: ohk I have `#include "stdio.h"` there, so `NULL` is not actually undefined...am checking whats going wrong in my workspace if this code is indeed correct...might be some external issue

Comment: save your file, and check that you are actually compiling the code you think you are compiling (e.g. edit the code and check that the compiler output changes)

Comment: gcc 4.8.1 just gives a warning: `warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration [enabled by default]` besides that everything works.

Comment: @Mahesha999 Do your get your error when building, or is the error generated by eclipse itself?

Comment: eclipse is giving itself. between I now think I should have mentioned that I don't have all this in same file...changed the code...very sorry

Comment: @Mahesha999 So this may be an error in the code verifications done by eclipse. Maybe you can build it anyway and see the same thing as any MinGW user in the build's result.

Comment: With edit I can now reproduce the bug.

Comment: thank u for trying it out...any guesses what stupidity am doing here?

Comment: @Mahesha999 found!

Comment: I shouldnt have switched from C to Java long back... :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix `algorithms.h`:

```
#ifndef ALGORITHMS_H
#define ALGORITHMS_H

extern StackEntry *createStack();

#endif /* ALGORITHMS_H */
```

(`extern` is not mandatory, it is good practice, but you DO need this `*`).

Answer (score 0):

The code below compiles OK - hope this helps (VSTO 2013 console app)

```
#include "stdafx.h"


typedef struct StackEntry
{
    int data;
    StackEntry *next;
};

StackEntry* createStack()
{
    return NULL;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    StackEntry *stack = createStack(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comment that you are using Eclipse, I think that Eclipse tries to be more clever than it is as usual...

This code can give a warning (*warning: typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]*, because as explained by @GrzegorzSzpetkowski your second `typedef` does not include a name and and such ignore the typedef.

But it is enough to disturb Eclipse that get lost and shows an unexistent error.

Answer (score -1):

Too many `StackEntry`s. You can do this:

```
struct _StackEntry; // there is such a struct, no matter where.

struct _StackEntry {
    int a;
    _StackEntry *next; // now the compiler knows that this is a valid type
}

typedef _StackEntry StackEntry; // add an alias of this type
```

Comment: Identifiers beginning with an underscore+capital are reserved in all contexts. Identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved in file scope. (C11 7.1.2) There's really no reason not to use the exact same name for the struct tag and the typedef anyway, since they inhabit different namespaces; giving the tag a decorated name just adds confusion.

Comment: lol, says "Too many StackEntrys" then posts code with even more StackEntry than the original code

Comment: @Leushenko, this shouldn't add too much confusion since, as far as I understand, only `StackEntry` will be used in the code, and the type with an underscore will just be there not confusing anyone.

Comment: @M.M, `StackEntry` and `_StackEntry` are different, aren't they?

Comment: Yes but it is not any improvement over the original

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the answer.  I wish I could comment, but unfortunately, I am just a newbie on this site.  I would try removing the typedef from your struct definiton:

```
typedef struct StackEntry StackEntry;
struct StackEntry
{
    int data;
    StackEntry *next;
};
```

Comment: Removing the `typedef` is a good idea, however it had no effect so this should not change the compiler's output.